# 'Invalid App ID' error when trying to login with Facebook using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-oauth

I am trying to implement the Facebook sign in method to my app, but I keep getting an error saying that my app ID is invalid and 'The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID'. I searched for all solutions I could find but none of them solved my problem. I have already provided both my app ID and Secret KEY to Firebase when activating the Facebook Authentication, and added

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">*My id*</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb*My id*</string>
```

to my string resource file. I have also added the OAuth redirect URI provided by Firebase to my Facebook App Settings.

I think there's no problem with my Java code because I am correctly redirected to my Facebook account page in Chrome when I click the 'Login with Facebook' button, but I can add it if you guys think it's necessary.

I have also added my key hash to my app in Facebook Developers Website. And, although my app is still in development (sandbox mode), I guess this is not the problem, as I'm an administrator

If there's something missing or confusing, please tell me so I can correct it. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of naming the string as "facebook_app_id", I named it "facebook_application_id". I don´t know why the quickstart told me no name it "facebook_app_id" after all. Thanks for anyone who was trying to figure it out, I could solve it!

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments, it needed to be changed from `facebook_app_id` to `facebook_application_id`. For some reason, the quickstart was misleading/wrong (or perhaps outdated).